# how to replace comma with semicolon and remove double quotes in file using a bat file

Tags: batch-file

Actually i am very poor at batch programming...

I have a csv file in which data is like this

```
"column1","column2","column2"
"value1","value2","value3"
```

I have to replace comma with semicolon and remove double quotes.

MY output should be like this..

```
 column1;column2;column2
 value1;value2;value3
```

I have tried like this..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims==" %%A in (input.csv) do (
  set string=%%A & echo !string:,=;! >> output.csv
)
```

it is replacing comma with semicolon (i dont know how it is) but how to remove double quotes....

Comment: Try it with `set string=%%~A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    (for /f tokens^=1^-3delims^=^,^" %%a in (input.csv) do (
        echo(%%a;%%b;%%c
    ))>output.csv
```

It the real case is as simple as it has been posted, just define the "problematic" characters as delimiters in the `for` command to get them removed.

Comment: Thanx for your reply @MC ND  .. Can I have an explanation of your code (if you dont mine)..is it works for all files????

Comment: What if i have 30 columns as in same format shown at top of this page??

Comment: @alluhur What does the code do? for each line in the input file, using the characters `,"` (and including the `"` as a delimiter is what makes all the `^` necessary to escape the delimiters in the `for` options string as quotes can not be used) as delimiters/field separator, take the three fields and output them separated with semicolons.

Comment: Ya.. perfectly it is working for 3 columns.. if i have 30 columns (really i am having 29) how can i execute this???

Comment: @alluhur, and no, if you have 30 columns this method should not be used (you can, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/2861476), but too much complication without need). You will need to continue with your original code using `set "var=%%A"` `set "var=!var:"=!"` `set "var=!var:,=;!"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method: in two passes it replaces all double quotes `\q` with nothing, and then replaces all `,` with `;`

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.csv" | repl "\q" "" x |repl "," ";" L >"newfile.csv"
```

**inputfile**

```
"column1","column2","column2"
"value1","value2","value3"
```

**outputfile**

```
column1;column2;column2
value1;value2;value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **MC ND** I used your answer, that worked right out of the box, and made a few *"improvments"*:

- 4 columns
- comma insted as delimiter
- change .csv to .txt-file

> ```
> @echo off        
>     setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
>     
>     (for /f tokens^=1^-4delims^=^,^" %%a in (input.csv) do (
>     
>         echo(%%a,%%b,%%c,%%4
>     
>     ))>output.txt
> ```

The input file as below:

> "column1","column2","column3","column4"
>
> "value1","value2","value3","value4"
>
> "value5","value6","value7","value8"

I added a row extra.