# A line of code in a batch file works fine unnested, doesn't work while in a for loop

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

Basically, I'm working on a batch file that would find specific files that don't include a specific character, then use a .jar file on these files. Here's the code that I have:

```
Set "pattern=$"

FOR /R "%PathToDirectory%" %%# in (*.class) Do (
    Echo %%~nx# | FIND /V "%pattern%" 1>NUL && (
        java -jar "somejar.jar" %%~# > test\%%~n#.java
    )
)
pause
```

I've checked what commands the .bat file calls out and the java call paths are valid (the .jar and the .bat are in the same directory), though the console outputs that: "The system cannot find the file specified". Same line of code that calles somejar.jar, but bruteforced (as in, the paths to the files are hard-coded in) and pretty much 1:1 to what the bat puts into the console, works just fine in another .bat file.

Safe to say, I'm confuzzled and spent more than I should have on this, so I'm asking here for a bit of help

Comment: Windows doesn't use the # character. It ain't never going to work.

Comment: If your paths contain spaces or special characters, the file references will not be correctly handled without quotes. Try with `java -jar "somejar.jar" "%%~#" > "test\%%~n#.java"`

Comment: @Noodles - Even though some MS documentation claims that FOR variables should be letters, in reality, almost all byte codes are viable, including #. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/1012053 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

put `pushd %~dp0` at the beginning of your batch file to change the working directory to the batch file's path. i'm assuming your somejar.jar is *not* in c:\windows\system32, where your script will run by default if double clicked.