# Delete all the columns except 1st column and 1st row in all the csv file in a folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have hundreds of csv files in one folder, having 9 columns ,wherein i want to delete last 8 columns and 1st row from all the files.

file looks like this [image]

Also I am not sure if I can overwrite the the same file which is edited. For now i am considering that it is possible. 
And if overwriting is not possible then it should save with same file name may be in different directory

Please suggest

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to use a batch file? It is possible via batch (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520313/dos-batch-script-to-parse-csv-file-and-output-a-text-file) but I would recommend implementing in another language.

Comment: Why? It's just a CSV that needs to be parsed using a comma delimiter. This is batch `for` loops 101.

Comment: Yes I need in batch file. I have one entire process in batch file where this is a part of that process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes you've put the batch file in the same directory as the csv files.

```
@echo off

for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.csv') do (
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2* delims=," %%B in (%%A) do (
        echo %%B>>newdata.csv
    )
    copy /y newdata.csv %%A
    del newdata.csv
)
```

And this code makes no assumptions about the location of your script, source csv files, or target folder:

```
@echo off

set source_folder=C:\path\to\your\csv\files
set target_folder=C:\path\to\your\output\folder

if not exist %target_folder% mkdir %target_folder%

for /f %%A in ('dir /b %source_folder%\*.csv') do (
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2* delims=," %%B in (%source_folder%\%%A) do (
    echo %%B>>%target_folder%\%%A
    )
)
```

Comment: It works great ,also can you suggest if my batch file is in other directory then how will the code look like

Comment: In the first for loop, you'd just change the part in parentheses to `('dir /b "C:\wherever\your\files\are\*.csv"')` - the quotes are only necessary if you have spaces anywhere in the path or filename.

Comment: And if not overwrite existing files then how do u save in different dir all the modified files? What would be the code in that case?

Comment: Then you'd delete the `copy` and `del` lines and set the directory path in the `echo %%B` line. For example, if you wanted to move the new csv files to a folder in the current directory and keep the edited filenames the same as their old filenames, you can say `echo %%B>>./newdir/%%A` - make sure the directory exists first, of course.

Comment: When I keep batch file in different dir it gives me a strange error saying "The system cannot find the file abc.csv. The system cannot find the file specified."

I made changes told by you above ('dir /b "C:\wherever\your\files\are\*.csv"')

Comment: %%B is taking the filename without the path and that's making the code assume the csv files are in the same path as the script. I've edited my answer to provide a solution that makes no assumptions about file locations.