# Batch - for loop parameter order

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I was trying to use tokens in a `for` loop to separate a CSV file in my batch file. Here's the code snippet:

```bat
for /f "tokens=1-31* delims=," %%a in ("!revamped!") do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
  ...
  echo %%y
  echo %%z
      rem what parameter should I use next?
)
```

After using `%%a` all the way to `%%z`, I have no idea which parameter should I use next.

**Question:** What is the order of using parameters *after* using all `%%a` to `%%z`  in a `for` loop?

Comment: [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) is your answer. You can use 31 tokens maximum (or use another `for`)

Comment: `*` is a token (in this case %%a) after which usage no other tokens can be used. After `z` comes `{` - check the ascii table. Though probably will be better to start with `%A` as upper case letters have smaller numbers in the ascii table. Mind that you are limited to `31` tokens. For more you'll need nested loop.

Comment: [I found a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/2152082) of nested `for` to use more than 31 tokens. (provided by dbenham)

Comment: @Stephan I know the 31 tokens limit, but I think `%%a` to `%%z` is only 26  tokens

Comment: @SteveFest see the two links, I gave you. Copying it for your convenience: `? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ]`

Comment: If you're evaluating CSV data, you could use just a plain `for` loop without any `/F` switch.  `for %%a in (!revamped!) do echo %%~a`.  `for` will split a string on unquoted commas, semicolons, spaces, and tabs, and there's no 31 token limit.

Comment: @SteveFest after z are `{` , `|` (which needs escaping) and `}` then is `<DEL>`  which cannot be used as token and is the last character in the not-extended ascii chars table.

Comment: @Stephan You need to make the "`for %%a` (CSV)" method as an answer as it worked like a charm for me!

Comment: We have a brand new thread over on Dostips.com that discusses this more in depth providing new options and concepts. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7703

Comment: @SteveFest: Note that your example does _not_ works as assumed. The `tokens=*` option specify _all the tokens_ returned in a single token-letter, so the `delims=` part don't matters in this case. Try: `for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("One,Two,Three") do echo a=%%a, b=%%b`; the output is: `a=One,Two,Three, b=%b`. To use _several tokens_ you always must specify _how many_ (maximum 31+1). For example: `for /f "tokens=1-31* delims=," %%? in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already pointed out in comments, [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is limited to 31 tokens. There are the following work-arounds:

1. Use nested `for /F` loops, like this (50 tokens are used here):

   ```cmd
   for /F "tokens=1-25* delims=," %%A in ("!revamped!") do (
       for /F "tokens=1-25* delims=," %%a in ("%%Z") do (
           echo token # 01: "%%A"
           echo token # 25: "%%Y"
           echo token # 26: "%%a"
           echo token # 50: "%%y"
           echo remaining tokens: "%%z"
       )
   )
   ```
2. Use a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to gain a practically unlimited number of tokens:

   ```cmd
   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("!revamped!") do (
       set /A "INDEX=0" & rem // (reset index number)
       set "LINE=%%A"
       rem /* In the following, every delimiter `,` is replaced by `" "`;
       rem    the entire line string is enclosed within `""`; hence
       rem    the result is a list of space-sepatated quoted tokens,
       rem    which can easily be handled by a standard `for` loop;
       rem    the surrounding quotes are later removed by the `~` modifier;
       rem    regard that the line string must not contain `*` or `?`: */
       for %%a in ("!LINE:,=" "!") do (
           set /A "INDEX+=1" & rem // (build index just for demonstration)
           echo token # !INDEX!: "%%~a"
       )
   )
   ```