# Batch file Find wildcard's value

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, findstr

I have a really bad script ( I know there are much easier ways to achieve this, but oh well.) that calculates your ip address.  It uses a very complicated and slow round-about method, but I am stuck.  I basically have this: A colossal txt file on my desktop with an IP address embedded into it.

Here's the code:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

cd\
cd users\%username%\desktop\
if exist "what is my ip address - Google Search.htm" del "what is my ip address -     Google Search.htm"
if exist ip.txt del ip.txt

:: this link is just a shortened url to a google search of "what is my ip address"
start http://goo.gl/L66owU
timeout 10 >nul /nobreak

%sendkeys% "(^s)"
timeout 1 >nul /nobreak
%sendkeys% "{enter}"
timeout 5 >nul /nobreak

rename "what is my ip address - Google Search.htm" "ip.txt"
findstr /c "Your public IP address is <em>.............</em>"  ip.txt
pause
goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

I cringe when looking at it.

Anyway, my bug is in this line `findstr /c "Your public IP address is <em>.............</em>"  ip.txt`  I need to filter out everything, and get whatever value is set as the wildcards (the `.......`s)

If you try out the script, you will basically have your default browser open up a google page, and then it will save that page as an HTM file (if you use chrome at least), and I then rename the `.html` to `.txt`.  I just need a better (and working) method of displaying the IP address in the end.

I know its possible, I'm just not very good with the `find` or `findstr` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for /f "tokens=6 delims=(" %%a in ('findstr /c:"Your public IP address is <em>"  ip.txt') do set ip="%%a"
set ip="%ip:*Your public IP address is <em>=%
set ip=%ip:~0,12%"
```

The problem is that Findstr returns the **full line** that contains the string specified so you would need a for loop to do the trick.
However, the for loop has a [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980791/number-of-tokens-limit-in-a-for-command-in-a-windows-batch-script) of 31 tokens so I chose the "(" for the delimiter.

Remember: This script will only work as long the most recent save location was on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There are various other option to do this very easily using VBS or other scripting langage.
You can use cURL too. Like this :

```
@echo off 
for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('curl ifconfig.me/ip') do echo Your External IP adress is : %%a
pause
```

If you want to use your solution it will be better to use this Url to get a smaller html file:

```
http://checkip.dyndns.org/
```

so here your code modified with this URL :

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

cd\
cd users\%username%\desktop\

:: this link is just a shortened url to a google search of "what is my ip address"
start http://checkip.dyndns.org/
timeout 10 >nul /nobreak

%sendkeys% "(^s)"
timeout 1 >nul /nobreak
%sendkeys% "{enter}"
timeout 5 >nul /nobreak
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "Current IP Check.htm" ^| find /i "Address"') do set $line=!%%a%!
echo Your external IP is : %$line:~1%
goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

;