# Batch For Loop Terminates Unexpectedly

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

I am having an issue with my for loop output.  There are 35 elements in each of the variables below, but when I run script, it only outputs 31 lines and then stops.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Script:

```
@ECHO off

ECHO LINE 1 > test.txt
SET VAR1=[01] [02] [03] [04] [05] [06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32] [33] [34] [35]
SET VAR2=5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95 100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175
SET numVar=1

For %%A in (%VAR1%) DO (
   call :forLoop2 
)
TYPE test.txt
PAUSE
EXIT

:forLoop2

For /F "tokens=%numVar%" %%B in ("%VAR2%") DO (
    SET /a numVar=%numVar%+1
    ECHO %%A INTO %%B >> test.txt
    EXIT /b
)
```

Output:

```
LINE 1 
[01] INTO 5 
[02] INTO 10 
[03] INTO 15 
[04] INTO 20 
[05] INTO 25 
[06] INTO 30 
[07] INTO 35 
[08] INTO 40 
[09] INTO 45 
[10] INTO 50 
[11] INTO 55 
[12] INTO 60 
[13] INTO 65 
[14] INTO 70 
[15] INTO 75 
[16] INTO 80 
[17] INTO 85 
[18] INTO 90 
[19] INTO 95 
[20] INTO 100 
[21] INTO 105 
[22] INTO 110 
[23] INTO 115 
[24] INTO 120 
[25] INTO 125 
[26] INTO 130 
[27] INTO 135 
[28] INTO 140 
[29] INTO 145 
[30] INTO 150 
[31] INTO 155
```

Comment: `for` can not process more than 31 tokens.

Comment: It is a limitation of `for /f`. See this answer [DOS batch script to parse CSV file and output a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of tokens limit in a FOR command in a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980791/number-of-tokens-limit-in-a-for-command-in-a-windows-batch-script)

Comment: Okay, thanks guys!