# With a batch file, how can I only use tokens 30 - 43 from a .txt file?

Tags: batch-file, token

I'm using a batch file to format a text file so that I can append it to an already populated .csv file automatically each hour.  My problem is, the text file's intended formatting isn't showing up in Notepad.  It opens as a single line with 43 tokens.  I only need tokens 30 - 43.  Since I can not skip lines and I'm over the token limit, what are my options?

Comment: Your best option is to not use batch.  There are many better choices, Powershell? Python?

Comment: batch is not suitable for complex processing. A hybrid solution or powershell would be much better

Comment: Please mark dbenham's answer as the answer for your question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't state what your token delimiter is, or whether any of your values contain quoted delimiters, or whether any tokens are empty (consecutive delimiters with nothing between them).

**Pure batch solution**

I will assume that your input is comma delimited. It is trivial to change the delimiter used by `FOR /F`.

I will also assume no values contain comma literals, and there are no consecutive commas. A simple `FOR /F` cannot handle either situation. Both could be solved with batch, (assuming the line is < 8kb), but it is a bit painful. If you have these issues, then I think you are better off with some other language than batch.

A single `FOR /F` command cannot parse more than 31 tokens. For more info, see

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/1012053
- [Number of tokens limit in a FOR command in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/980791/1012053)

But you don't need to parse any tokens past 29 :-)

You can simply use `FOR /F` with `"delims=29*"`, and the `*` "token" will contain tokens 30-43.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=29* delims=," %%A in ("yourInputFile.ext") do (echo(%%B) >>yourOutput.csv
```

If your input delimiter is something other than a comma, then you can store tokens 30-43 in a variable, and then use find/replace to substitute commas for the pipes.

For example, if your input parameter is a pipe, then

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=29* delims=|" %%A in ("yourInputFile.ext") do set "line=%%B"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if defined line set "line=!line:|=,!"
(echo(!line!) >>yourOutput.csv
```

I did not put the manipulation and write operations within the loop because you state your input has only one line.

I do not enable delayed expansion until after the loop completes just in case your input contains `!` literals. Expansion of `FOR /F` variables will corrupt `!` values if delayed expansion is enabled.

**Robust JREPL.BAT solution (hybrid batch/JScript)**

If your input violates any of the restrictions that I laid out in the pure batch solution, then you could use [JREPL.BAT - A regular expression command line text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

Since you did not specify your input format, I will assume it is CSV. The following solution will simply remove the first 29 tokens. It supports empty tokens, as well as quoted tokens with comma literals.

```
call jrepl "^(\q([^\q]|\q\q)*\q,|[^,]*,){29}" "" /x /f yourFile.ext >>yourOutput.csv
```

I'm sure there is an efficient JREPL solution if your input is not csv format. But I am not going to waste my time trying to guess your format.

Comment: There is an exclamation mark missing in the second last line.

Comment: @LotPings - Thanks, all fixed

Comment: Arrived at work with a beautiful solution here waiting for me!  Thanks so much!  Your one line of code works perfectly.  After your code I added JREPL to substitute double commas ",," with single comma delims "," and now everything is good.